# How to remove certain characters from a dictionary in python?

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose I have a dictionary with following keys:values

```
{A1:2345, A2:23, A3:1}
```

I just want to remove '23' from A1 and expected the output to be

```
{A1:45, A2:23, A3:1}
```

Please advice

Comment: What is the type of the elements? Strings?

Comment: Furthermore what should happen if `23` occurs twice, for instance `'23452345'`...

Comment: Yes it is strings

Comment: That will not happen 23 will not occur twice.

Answer (score 1):

Since based on your comments, `23` will only occur once, you can call [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re.sub#re.sub) on the string and write it back to the dictionary. So if the dictionary is named `dic`:

```
import re

dic['A1'] = re.sub('23','',dic['A1'],1)
```

The `,1` is optional and says you will only substitute the first occurrence (but it can improve efficiency a tiny bit). For example:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> dic={'A1':'2345', 'A2':'23', 'A3':'1'}
>>> import re
>>> dic['A1'] = re.sub('23','',dic['A1'],1)
>>> dic
{'A2': '23', 'A3': '1', 'A1': '45'}
```

**EDIT**:

based on your comment, you want to remove `2`s and `3`s from the values of all elements, except `'A9'`. You can achieve this with a `for` loop:

```
import re

for key,val in dic.items():
    if key != 'A9':
        dic[key] = re.sub('2|3','',val)
```

The pipe (`|`) in the regex functions as an "or". So:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> dic={'A1':'5', 'A2':'1', 'A3': '2379', 'A4':'8', 'A5':'37', 'A6':'379', 'A7':'6', 'A8':'4', 'A9':'23'}
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> for key,val in dic.items():
...     if key != 'A9':
...         dic[key] = re.sub('2|3','',val)
... 
>>> dic
{'A3': '79', 'A2': '1', 'A4': '8', 'A6': '79', 'A1': '5', 'A8': '4', 'A5': '7', 'A9': '23', 'A7': '6'}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Is there a way where I can iterate over the entire dictionary like {A1:5, A2:1, A3: 2379, A4:8, A5:37, A6:379, A7:6, A8:4, A9:23} and expect the output to be like {A1:5, A2:1, A3:79, A4:8, A5:7, A6:79, A7:6, A8:4, A9:23}

Comment: @KinshukSrivastava: The value for `A9` in your example is not altered... Is that a mistake?

Comment: No Wilem that's not a mistake. I know A9 has 23 and I want to remove all the occurrences of 2 and 3 from dictionary leaving A9.

Comment: So regardless of its value A9 should not be iterated?

Comment: Yup I have already stored that A9 and leaving that I want to remove every occurrence of 2 & 3

Comment: Ah you want to remove occurrences of `2` and `3` so if only `2` occurs, you want to remove that as well.

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to remove '23' from A1 .... That will not happen 23 will
>   not occur twice

In your simple case, it would be enough to use `repr()` function:

```
d = {'A1':2345, 'A2':23,'A3':1}
d['A1'] = int(repr(d['A1'])[2:]) # getting slice of characters starting from index 2

print(d)
```

The output:

```
{'A1': 45, 'A3': 1, 'A2': 23}
```

---

If all values are strings, it comes even more simpler:

```
d['A1'] = d['A1'][2:]
```

Comment: I don't want the index to be fixed. Is there a way where I can iterate over the entire dictionary like {A1:5, A2:1, A3: 2379, A4:8, A5:37, A6:379, A7:6, A8:4, A9:23} and expect the output to be like {A1:5, A2:1, A3:79, A4:8, A5:7, A6:79, A7:6, A8:4, A9:23}

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, have a look at the second part of my answer `d['A1'] = d['A1'][2:]`

Comment: But still it is unsafe, since the question is to remove `23`, it is possible that `d['A1']` is `1234`.